# Prestashop fix a max total_shipping

Tags: php, max, prestashop-1.6

I set a shipping cost for every product, but I want to fix a max of the total order shipping cost to 200$, if it exceeds 200$.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by modifiying `getTotalShippingCost` function in `classes\Cart.php` :

I added

```
$total_shipping = $total_shipping > 180 ? 180 : $total_shipping;
```

before `return $total_shipping;`